# null data received from server php using retrofit, but response is success

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit

I am trying to learn retrofit. It looks like the response received is success, but there is no data.
The php file works fine, I have checked it using postman. On postman i am receiving a response, but not on my App.

Below is my code :

**ApiInterface File :**

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded // annotation used in POST type requests
    @POST("/login.php")     // API's endpoints
    public void login(@Field("Login") String login, Callback<JSONObject> callback);
}
```

**Api File :**

```
public class Api {

    public static ApiInterface getClient() {
        RestAdapter adapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(Constants.base_url).build();
        ApiInterface api = adapter.create(ApiInterface.class);
        return api;
    }
}
```

**MainActivity File : (the below code is called on button click)**

```
private void signUp() {
        Api.getClient().login(convert_JSON, new Callback<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void success(JSONObject loginResponse, Response response) {
                try {
                    Toast.makeText(Login.this, loginResponse.get("message").toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.i("viky123", e.getMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.i("viky", error.toString());
            }
        });
    }
```

**Below is the error showning that JSON object key 'message' has no value. This error is caught in catch block of success method in MainActivity File :**

```
2021-08-29 19:54:24.859 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err: org.json.JSONException: No value for message
2021-08-29 19:54:24.860 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:399)
2021-08-29 19:54:24.860 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err:     at com.example.panshoptrail.Login$1.success(Login.java:100)
2021-08-29 19:54:24.860 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err:     at com.example.panshoptrail.Login$1.success(Login.java:92)
2021-08-29 19:54:24.860 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err:     at retrofit.CallbackRunnable$1.run(CallbackRunnable.java:45)
2021-08-29 19:54:24.861 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
2021-08-29 19:54:24.861 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
2021-08-29 19:54:24.861 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
2021-08-29 19:54:24.861 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7560)
2021-08-29 19:54:24.861 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2021-08-29 19:54:24.862 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
2021-08-29 19:54:24.862 3372-3372/com.example.panshoptrail W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

Comment: `Response response` Where do you use it?

Comment: @blackapps Nowhere. This is the first time I am using retrofit and followed the code from the following link : https://abhiandroid.com/programming/retrofit
But I have tried to change it according to my requirement

Comment: That is not the answer i expected. Moreover you did not tell what you would try now.

Comment: "org.json.JSONException: No value for message" the message could possibility be empty/null. what is convert_JSON here ?

Comment: @ImranAli I store the username and password in JSONObject, then convert it to string and store it in convert_json(convert_json is a String). Then I pass convert_json in login method of ApiInterface.

Comment: @blackapps I don't know what to do. I am trying to keep data in JSON format for sending as well as receiving. If this doesn't work, then I will follow the instructions of the link and try

Comment: `Response response` You did not use it you said. But did you try it meanwhile? That you were supposed to do. But you did not report.

Comment: Does the message received from the server is indeed empty? Can you test using Postman and verify that it is not empty?

Comment: @gioravered Yes, I have already checked with postman. It is receiving response. If you want I can also share my php code.

Comment: @blackapps Yes, I looked into it. But I don't know what to do with it. There is a method of response getBody(). I am guessing it will do something. Checking it right now.

Comment: btw, the example you've used is using Retrofit1 (old). You better use Retrofit2 (new)

Comment: @gioravered Tried with retrofit2. Same issue.

Comment: With Retrofit2 you can use Callback<ResponseBody> and then parse the response manually or (better in my opinion) create a POJO with the fields of the received json and use Callback<YourObject>.